# "Will all be" or "will be all" or "all will be"?

Tags: word-order

Which one of these is correct, if I want to say something akin to "everything is going to be okay":

> This will all be over soon.

> This all/These all will be over soon.

> This will be all over soon.

Comment: You want to use "to be over", not "to be all over".

Comment: @Centaurus I took the third sentence from a title song by the way, so the third sentence is incorrect?

Comment: Not incorrect but, depending on context, it can be ambiguous.  For instance, he used to kiss me on the cheek but it's all over now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual with "Which of these is correct?" questions, they're all correct.

But they use different constructions, and can mean slightly different things (though most likely they don't).

First, the plural *These* (whatever unpleasant events they are) is odd here, unless there's some special reason in the context (whatever that might be) to mention that there is more than one unpleasant event, while attempting to comfort someone. Ordinarily that would not be a useful approach. So we'll limit discussion to (renumbering for convenience)

1. *This will be **all** over soon.*
2. *This will **all** be over soon.*
3. *This **all** will be over soon.*

Except for the position of *all*, which moves, everything else stays put. And there's another equally grammatical position for *all*, as well:

4. ***All** this will be over soon.*

(1-4) can be used to describe the same situation, though they're not quite synonymous. (1) contains the fixed temporal phrase *all over/all done*, which means 'completely finished'; the other sentences don't invoke this idiom.

The last 3, on the other hand, are synonymous transformations. (4) is the basic sentence, with the quantifier *all* modifying the noun phrase (*this*, whatever it represents). Quantifiers (like *all, every, each, some, few, many*) modify noun phrases; they normally precede the nouns they modify, like adjectives (they have to come before all the adjectives, though)

- ***All** (of) the big brown Victorian townhouses are for sale*

Some quantifiers (including *all* and *each*, but **not** including *every*) can undergo the transformation called "Quantifier-Floating" (*Q-Float* for short), which allows these quantifiers to appear at ("float to") different adverbial positions. Essentially, it allows these quantifiers to masquerade as adverbs like *reportedly*, which can go in many positions, especially before and after the first auxiliary verb.

- ***All** the big houses are for sale* ~ ***Reportedly** the big houses are for sale*
- *The big houses **all** are for sale* ~ *The big houses **reportedly** are for sale*
- *The big houses are **all** for sale* ~ *The big houses are **reportedly** for sale*

Q-float also works for *each*, though the verb agreement changes because *each* is singular, whereas *all* is plural.

- ***Each** of the houses/**Each** house is for sale ~ The houses **each** are/are **each** for sale.*

but Q-float doesn't work for *every*:

- ***Every** house is for sale.* ~ **The houses every are for sale* ~ **The houses are every for sale*

Comment: This is interesting. I like the name "Q-Float" and its function as well. It seems not all open-class -ly adverbs (adjective +ly) act like this Q-Float though many of them can go in several different positions.

Comment: Adverbs don't Q-float. That's only for certain quantifiers. Adverbs have their own syntax rules, which often have to do with semantics and pragmatics (unlike most syntax). _Adverb_ is something of a wastebasket category, so it has a lot of subclasses, each with its own set of peculiarities.